# como diferenciar caracteres en c++

Tags: c++

he estado intentado hacer un menú simple , mi problema consiste que al   momento de ingresar 's', necesito que solo aparezca la palabra hasta luego y se termine el programa, pero en vez esta apareciendo también todo lo demás o sea lo de "resultado de la operación es:" y luego si muestra el hasta luego y termina el programa.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool repetir=true;
    char opcion;
    int resul=0,error=0;

    cout<<"\t MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<"+: SUMA"<<endl;
    cout<<"-: Resta"<<endl;
    cout<<"*: Multiplicacion"<<endl;
    cout<<"/: Dividir "<<endl;
    cout<<"%: Potencia"<<endl;
    cout<<"!: Factorial"<<endl;
    cout<<"S: salir"<<endl;


    while(repetir==true){

    cout<<"Eliga una opcion:";
    cin>>opcion;
    if(opcion!='S'||opcion!='s' ){
        cout<<"el resultado de la operacion ("<<opcion<<") es: "<<resul<<endl;
        cout<<"error: "<<error<<endl;
        repetir=true;
      }


        if(opcion=='s'|| opcion=='S'){
            cout<<"hasta pronto"<<endl;
        repetir=false;
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La condición no está implementada correctamente porque en el primer if, si opción='s', la segunda condición va a ser verdadera mientras la primera falsa. Lo que significa que la expresión en general será verdadera.

Toma en consideración que en la operación OR:

```
verdadero OR verdadero == verdadero
falso OR verdadero == verdadero
verdadero OR falso == verdadero
falso OR falso == falso
```

Para evitar ese pequeño problemita puedes simplificar tu expresión utilizando la función tolower()

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool repetir=true;
    char opcion;
    int resul=0,error=0;

    cout<<"\t MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<"+: SUMA"<<endl;
    cout<<"-: Resta"<<endl;
    cout<<"*: Multiplicacion"<<endl;
    cout<<"/: Dividir "<<endl;
    cout<<"%: Potencia"<<endl;
    cout<<"!: Factorial"<<endl;
    cout<<"S: salir"<<endl;


    while(repetir==true){

        cout<<"Eliga una opcion:";
        cin>>opcion;
        if(tolower(opcion)!='s'){
            cout<<"el resultado de la operacion ("<<opcion<<") es: "<<resul<<endl;
            cout<<"error: "<<error<<endl;
            repetir=true;
        }


        if(tolower(opcion)=='s'){
            cout<<"hasta pronto"<<endl;
            repetir=false;
        }

    }
}
```

De esta forma no debes distinguir entre una ‘s’ mayúscula y una minúscula y evitas el problema de la doble condición para cada if

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema en la línea:

```
if(opcion!='S'||opcion!='s' ){
```

Lo que tu quieres hacer es:

```
if(opcion!='S' && opcion!='s' ){
```

Fíjate que uno es un OR y el otro es un AND.

Por otro lado, fíjate que los 2 ifs son excluyentes, por lo que basta con poner un if-else.